# validateTree in Java 7.x doesnt work (in Java 6.x was fine)

Tags: java, swing, java-7, java-6

My version of java is:

> Java Plug-in 10.3.1.255 Using JRE version 1.7.0_03-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

So when I had version 6.x everything was fine, after upgrading I've got this:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This function should be called while holding treeLock
        at java.awt.Component.checkTreeLock(Component.java:1196)
        at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1682)
        at pl.recorder.ScenarioWindow.showUploadPanel(PlayerWindow.java:721)
        at pl.recorder.actions.UploadFilesAction.execute(DesignFilesAction.java:71)
        at pl.recorder.actions.EndTestAction.actionPerformed(EndTestAction.java:91)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I changed `validateTree()` to `validate()` and suprise ;) - everthing works fine, but I dont know if this change will work also on java 6.x (I guess not). How I can change this code to work in Java 6x and 7x.

Comment: What code? See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 11):

"It's not a bug, it's a feature" of java 7 ;)

> *This function should be called while holding treeLock*

This is to force you writing :

```
synchronized(getTreeLock()) {
     validateTree();
}
```

Comment: Just received one of this issues when one of my older programs stopped working when I assume client updated their Java to 1.7. This solved the issue :) In my case I wanted to make sure the operations are done when the size of containing components is known and validate was not enough.

Answer (score 9):

In response to @vince's Answer, I think it is instructive to look at what the [Java 1.4.2 javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validateTree%28%29) for the method says:

> `protected void validateTree()`
>
> Recursively descends the container tree and recomputes the layout for any subtrees marked as needing it (those marked as invalid). *Synchronization should be provided by the method that calls this one: `validate`.*

(Emphasis added.)

The way I read this, it is saying that the method is *designed* to be called by `validate()` which will (presumably) be holding the tree lock.

Note that the text is identical in Java 6 and Java 7.  The spec has not changed ...

Now apparently there is application code out there that is calling `validateTree()` directly ... without acquiring the tree lock.  Presumably, this results in unreproducible problems (Heisenbugs) when the end user clicks too fast or something.  Presumably, the change in Java 7 is designed to bring this incorrect / buggy use of `validateTree()` to developers' attention.

OK, so this is short-term pain.  But the long term, *everyone* wins (apart from the lawyers :-) ):

- Oracle doesn't get bug reports for strange unreproducible behaviour that is really the application programmer's problem.
- Developers don't get bug reports from customers for strange unreproducible behaviour.
- End users get applications that work better.

Comment: I know this is old, but this helped me and I like to add my two cents. `validateTree` is protected, so you should call `validate` instead (it does the synchonized steps). Also, in Java 7 they added a call to `checkTreeLock()` on `validateTree`, that's why the error happens