# How can I edit a .class file to fix validateTree error in Java 7

Tags: java, swing, java-7, java-6

A friend of mine delivers Java applets and since his clients moved to Java 7, they started running into this issue:
[validateTree in Java 7.x doesnt work (in Java 6.x was fine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758069/validatetree-in-java-7-x-doesnt-work-in-java-6-x-was-fine)

The solution seems to be to wrap the call to `validateTree` as in:

```
synchronized(getTreeLock()) {
     validateTree();
}
```

**I do not have the source .java file.**

- Is there a Java ByteCode Editor+Decompiler that would let me edit in those lines in plain-text Java?
- If I do have to edit the .class file in bytecode, what are the instructions?

---

My view of the file with `jd-gui` (which does not let me edit the file though):

```
public final class XApplet extends JApplet
  implements ActionListener
public void init()
{
  ...
  validateTree();
}
```

Comment: Is your friend by accident the person of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12821047/1076463)

Comment: @Robin :) No and although the approach is interesting. It would not help us in this case as we cannot control the runtimes of the people who download the applet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Java decompiler like [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) or [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/) to obtain a decompiled source code, then solve the problem in code and recompile your class. You need to decompile the code, not only show it.

PD: If he is your friend, you can get the source code, isn't it? It would be easier...

Comment: The decompiled source code depends on a large number of other files. My friend is on vacation with no access to source files in the near future o__O

Comment: if you can decompile it, you can recompile it. you have all the class files.

Comment: does a `.jar` file not depend on any external, in .NET parlance, 'assemblies'?

Comment: a JAR can depend on external resources, obviously. but it is not related with the decompilation and the recompilation. why do you ask it?